# Microsoft SharePoint is not supported with version 4.0.30319.225

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint

I'm using SharePoint 2010, Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate Edition with SP1. In my Console Project, I targeted .net framework 4.0, same with all the other 10 projects in the solution.

I did this to make the NSAPConnector work. NSAPConnector is the .net connector we used in consuming SAP BAPI functions.

Is there a work around for this setup to work? Or I would have to retarget all projects to .net framework 3.5? If I do that then the NSAPConnector will not work any more.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The requirements for SharePoint 2010 ( https://technet.microsoft.com/library/cc262485(v=office.14).aspx ) list Microsoft .NET Framework version 3.5 SP1 as a hard requirement.  SharePoint 2010 isn't supported (and as you can see) doesn't work any other version of .Net.

You aren't clear on what integrations you are doing with SharePoint.  If you doing have to tie in directly to server side SharePoint hooks, you can remotely integrate with SharePoint via SOAP APIs, SharePoint's Client Side Object Model and its REST APIs.  This would free you up to use a client .Net Framework that is compatible with your SAP library.

If you need to tie into SharePoint server side, then you will need to host your SAP connecting code out of process (say for example as a Windows service or behind a web service interface and have your SharePoint Server code interact with your service/web service end point.

Comment: Hi Mark, Thanks for your answer. I was successful in adding reference to SharePoint.dll but it says not supported with version 4.0 when I run my c# code in Visual Studio 2010. All projects targeted net4.0. Here's part of  my code:

   SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
            {
    --some lines of codes--
            });
Any idea? I mark your answer as accepted.